# Ubuntu server auto install

Tags: ubuntu

Hello i am working on some automation, and ran into an issue where ubuntu auto install still asks for a verification in middle of installation.

> Even if a fully noninteractive autoinstall config is found, the server
> installer will ask for confirmation before writing to the disks unless
> autoinstall is present on the kernel command line. This is to make it
> harder to accidentally create a USB stick that will reformat a machine
> it is plugged into at boot. Many autoinstalls will be done via
> netboot, where the kernel command line is controlled by the netboot
> config – just remember to put autoinstall in there!

i came across this article, and in my config file i do have "autoinstall" like this:

```
#cloud-config
  autoinstall:
   version: 1
```

How do i put it on kernel command line ? or how do i write a netboot config ? i am a bit new to server administration and not familiar with most of the terms.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, this double check is performed in order to prevent accidental installs when using physical media to install OS. To start fully automatic install one should use net-install over FTP or HTTP.